# Двоеточие внутри прямой речи?

Tags: пунктуация

Мальчишка посмотрел на меня, как на говорящего осла: 
— Я не знаю, что ты сказал, но здесь их нет подавно**:** не женское это дело — попадаться на глаза власть имущим.

Такое возможно?

Comment: Да, вполне корректно. Двоеточие здесь поставлено, поскольку далее идет пояснение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, на прямую речь не похоже предложение. Поэтому первое тире надо убрать. А так, такое предложение вполне возможно.

Comment: Я знаю, что предложение возможно. Загвоздка в том, что это прямая речь персонажа. Мне посоветовали поставить двоеточие вместо запятой (т.к. идёт пояснение), но я ни разу не видела его в прямой речи.

Comment: Если само предложение в контексте( который вы не предоставили), оформлена как прямая, то такое оформление вполне возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Никак не могу понять, почему здесь некоторые из отвечающих не видят  слов автора. Они есть:Мальчишка посмотрел на меня, как на говорящего осла (подразумевается: и произнес, сказал):
— Я не знаю, что ты сказал, но здесь их нет подавно...
Розенталь пишет о таких случаях, что слова, "посмотрел, усмехнулся, рассмеялся, вздохнул" и многие другие, обозначающие  жесты, мимику, движения, допускают возможность добавить к ним глагол речи (улыбнулся и сказал, посмотрел и крикнул и т.п. В таких случаях ставится двоеточие. Один из примеров от Розенталя, похожий на наше предложение: Он глянул с усмешкой:
 -Ничего, до свадьбы заживет.

Comment: Виктор, слова автора появились уже потом. Сперва их не было. Поэтому и вопрос был не понят .Совершено верно. У Розенталя это правило есть. Но и вы не поняли вопроса. Автора интересовал вопрос , можно ли поставить двоеточие после слова "подавно", а не после слов автора. Слова автора как раз не вызывают сомнения.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, заголовок Вашего вопроса крайне некорректен. Почему? Во-первых, двоеточие в прямой речи ставится в том случае, если слова автора (помечаются значком «А») находятся перед прямой речью (обозначается значком «П»). 
Женя спросил: «Какие игры ты любишь, Адольф?».

Я отвечаю, следуя Вашему заголовку — двоеточие при прямой речи.

Если же Вы имеете в виду двоеточие при прямой речи, то прямая речь оформляет так же, как и обычные предложения.

Comment: Читайте внимательно. Не «ПРИ» прямой речи, а «В».

Comment: Анака, предложение не похоже на прямую речь. Где слова автора?

Comment: Так лучше?

Answer (score 0):

Текст можно оформить следующим образом:

Мальчишка посмотрел на меня, как на говорящего осла. (Нет двоеточия).

— Я не знаю, что ты сказал, но здесь их нет подавно. Не женское это дело — попадаться на глаза власть имущим.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Двоеточие внутри прямой речи не то чтобы запрещается, но не характерно, так как требует увеличенной паузы. Соответственно, вместо двоеточия лучше использовать тире. Но тире здесь уже есть, поэтому разбиваем текст на два предложения.

ПО ПОВОДУ ДВОЕТОЧИЯ

Одинцова опять усмехнулась.

-Вы решительно не хотите верить, что я способна увлекаться?

Базаров исподлобья взглянул на нее.

-Любопытством - пожалуй; но не иначе.

Comment: Согласен, такой действительно лучше.